# Get current image path

Tags: c#, wpf, image

how do I get the current path of an image in wpf?

I am trying to build a generic function that changes the image to other image by just adding a "focus" to the end of the name of the image, btu can't seem to get the current path so I can make the change

any idea?

EDIT:

```
private void image1_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        string buf = ((BitmapImage)(sender as Image).Source).UriSource.ToString();
        string pack = buf.Substring(0, buf.LastIndexOf('.')) + "focus" + buf.Substring(buf.LastIndexOf('.'));

        SetImageFullURI(sender as Image, pack);
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
<Window x:Class="Jode_NumeroDePeito.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="493" Width="1019" UseLayoutRounding="True" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <Border BorderBrush="#FFEBEBEB" BorderThickness="1" Height="207" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,11,0,0" Name="border1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="206" CornerRadius="5"></Border>
    <Image Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,33,0,0" Name="btPastaArtes" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="261" Source="/Jode_NumeroDePeito;component/Images/botao.jpg" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" MouseEnter="image1_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="imgEscolherArtes_MouseLeave" Cursor="Hand" />
    <Image Cursor="Hand" Height="21" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="52,19,0,0" Name="image1" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Source="/Jode_NumeroDePeito;component/Images/passo1.jpg" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="97" />
    <Border BorderBrush="#FFEBEBEB" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" Height="207" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,233,0,0" Name="border2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="206" />
    <Image Cursor="Hand" Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,255,0,0" Name="btCSV" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Source="/Jode_NumeroDePeito;component/Images/botao.jpg" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="261" MouseEnter="image1_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="imgEscolherArtes_MouseLeave" />
    <Image Cursor="Hand" Height="21" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="52,241,0,0" Name="image3" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Source="/Jode_NumeroDePeito;component/Images/passo2.jpg" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="97" />
    <Border BorderBrush="#FFEBEBEB" BorderThickness="1" Height="429" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="237,11,0,0" Name="border3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="338" AllowDrop="False" CornerRadius="5"></Border>
    <Image Cursor="Hand" Height="21" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="265,19,0,0" Name="image2" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Source="/Jode_NumeroDePeito;component/Images/passo3.jpg" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="97" />
    <TextBlock Height="136" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,74,0,0" Name="txtLogArtes" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="181" />
    <TextBlock Height="136" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,295,0,0" Name="txtLogCSV" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="181" />
    <Image Cursor="Hand" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="564,161,0,0" Name="lblPreset" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Source="/Jode_NumeroDePeito;component/Images/configIllustrator.jpg" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="116" />
    <ComboBox Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="552,172,0,0" Name="selPreset" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132" />
    <Image Cursor="Hand" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="729,161,0,0" Name="lblInit" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Source="/Jode_NumeroDePeito;component/Images/inicio.jpg" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="116" />
    <TextBox Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="686,172,0,0" Name="txtInit" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Image Cursor="Hand" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="816,161,0,0" Name="lblQnt" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Source="/Jode_NumeroDePeito;component/Images/qnt.jpg" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="116" />
    <TextBox Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="808,172,0,0" Name="txtQnt" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Border BorderBrush="#FFEBEBEB" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="544,153,0,0" Name="pnGeneric" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="429" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <Image Cursor="Hand" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="930,163,0,0" Name="imgFechar" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Source="/Jode_NumeroDePeito;component/Images/x.jpg" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="35" />
    <Image Cursor="Hand" Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="249,33,0,0" Name="btAdd" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Source="/Jode_NumeroDePeito;component/Images/adic.jpg" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="261" />
    <Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="0" Height="357" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="242,75,0,0" Name="pnContainer" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="329" />
    <Image Cursor="Hand" Height="21" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="611,19,0,0" Name="image4" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Source="/Jode_NumeroDePeito;component/Images/passo3.jpg" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="97" />
    <Image Cursor="Hand" Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="595,33,0,0" Name="btImprimir" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Source="/Jode_NumeroDePeito;component/Images/adic.jpg" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="261" />
    <TextBlock Height="168" Margin="636,241,210,0" Name="txtLog" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

thanks,
Joe

Comment: Where does this image come in the first place?

Comment: it is normally added at the designer

Comment: How is it added?  As a Resource?  Content?

Comment: I added the image to the project and then choosen it as the source for the Image control, and the image property says it is a resource compile

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the underlying source for your `Image` in your code behind like this...where `i` is your defined `Image` coming from XAML or defined elsewhere. In this example `path` is not used; however you will make use of it when you append `focus` as mention in your question.

```
Image i = new Image();

BitmapImage bi = i.Source as BitmapImage;
bi.BeginInit();

Uri uri = bi.UriSource;
String path = uri.AbsolutePath;
String newPath = @"C:\Images\blah.png";
Uri newUri = new Uri(newPath);

bi.UriSource = newUri;
bi.EndInit();
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your code try this...

```
string buf = ((BitmapFrame)(sender as Image).Source).BaseUri.ToString();
```

Comment: this gives me an error because i.Source isn't an BitmapImage. It can become bitmapimage if I set it from code, but the IDE gives it another type when you set the source through it

Comment: i.Source is an ImageSource property which BitmapImage inherits; what is the exact error and where?

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrameDecode' to type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage'.

Comment: @Jonathon What is the type coming back; what type are you calling the Source property from? Some code in your post may be helpful...

Comment: added the mouse enter function in the edit of the post, thanks for oyur replies

Comment: Aaron, I tried your code, bur BaseUri returns the main window xaml and not the image source...

Comment: @Jonathan How are you adding these images; step by step instructions within your orig post or screenshots may help; since usually the underlying XAML is still there and accessible...missing something...your XAML would be handy as well...

Comment: I add the image throught the ide, by draging the "Image" icon to the form, then click the source and choose an image from the resource, using visual studio 2010 btw

Comment: @Jonathon This isn't WPF is it? Is this WinForms?

Comment: So what does the underlying XAML look like of your MainWindow.xaml?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BitmapImage` objects, and point your `image.Source` to them when necessary

BitmapImage has `bitmapImage.UriSource` property

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. What I am doing is adding Image through the IDE and setting an image thrugh the properties tab of the IDE, how can I do this with BitmapImage?